# How does checking for "submit button is pressed" work?

Tags: php

I'm curious about this kind of behavior. Suppose the code below:

```
<form name="myfrom" action="" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="username" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Submit" />
</form>

<?php
    if($_POST['submit_form'] == "Submit") {
        echo "do something";
    }
?>
```

What is the reason it works? Is that because when you click on the submit button the page reloads again and then the PHP script runs again? Is there an explanation?

Comment: Yes, when you don't submit the form, the if condition is false.

Comment: Now seriously: open chrome dev tools and see what the data your script sends to itself. Then have a read on what `$_POST` is (assuming you already know what HTTP POST is)

Comment: Go read about forms somewhere! When you click submit the browser will send a POST request, which you are detecting in the `if` statement.

Comment: And activate error reporting so you'll see just how badly the condition fails before you submit the form.

Comment: When you leave the `action` field of your form empty the form will send the data (contained in the `$_POST` array) to itself again. That is why you experience a "page reload". The button will send its value `'Submit'` in the array element `$_POST['submit_form']`.

Comment: @cars10: "When you leave the àction` field of your form empty the form will send the data to itself again" --- that's not right

Comment: @zerkms *Please*, explain to us what *really* happens. I readily admit that did not like my own expression 'to itself' very much.

Comment: @cars10: browser sends POST, webserver accepts it. That's it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you mean, **how to test when the form is submitted** try this:

```
<form name="myfrom" action="" method="post">
    Username: <input type="text" name="user" id="username" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit_form" value="Submit" />
</form> 

<?php if(isset($_POST['user'])) {
    echo "do something";
}
?>
```

and if you test `if($_POST['submit_form'] == "Submit")` you get true.. i.e 1...

When ever you submit any PHP form with POST method then the following happens behind the scenes:

- The server takes the values of all the HTML input elements and takes their names too...
- Then the server, puts the names and values in the POST array in the following fashion:

`{'name1'=>'value1','name2'=>'value2','name3'=>'value3','name4'=>'value4'...'name_n_'=>'value_n_'}`

You change the value of a text field by entering some text into it. However, the user can't really change the value of a submit button, i.e. the displayed text on a submit button, hence whenever you say `echo $_POST['submit_form']` you will always get the value that you set in HTML i.e. *Submit*

hope that helps...

Comment: I mean what exactly happens behind the scenes. In this case, I'm interested in how is the php behavior in this kind of situation after the user clicks on submit button.

Comment: @bpinhosilva: php doesn't care of any buttons, it only cares of HTTP request (POST in this case)

Comment: see, basically whenever you submit a form and use the post method. all the values of all the input fields are added to the POST dictionary. So the post dict. looks like this: {'user'=>'What_ever_you_entered_in_the_text_field','submit_form'=>'Submit'} @bpinhosilva

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi, I saw it, very good thanks! I know how the POST organizes the data, I just would like to know if the page reloads again and if this is why the php catches the defined submit...

Comment: Yes @bpinhosilva the page reloads and during the reload the information is sent to the server..

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi sorry, not enough points to accept it..

Comment: @AnshumanDwibhashi it asks for 15 to upvote, I have just 5. Sorry..